# grep variable string in file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, match

I must find in a file this string:

```
200 https://www.example.example
```

The value 200 is randomic, I must find every HTTP return code (ex 200, 301, 404 etc...etc)

How can I grep only this string with return code variable (I don't want specify every return code in grep command)?

```
cat file.txt | grep "*** http*"
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. Try to read [ask] and provide a [mcve] so we can understand better. It is important to provide a relevant input and the desired output.

Comment: What about just taking the first 3 characters of each line?

Comment: `grep "*** http*"` is not close to the regexp you want. You should find some kind of regexp tutorial if you're going to be trying to use any tools that use regexps (grep, sed, awk, perl, ruby, etc....).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want to match any line starting with a three digit number, followed by "http"?

```
grep -E '^[0-9]{3} http' file.txt
```

More accurate as suggested by fedorqui (thanks) would be this:

```
grep -E '^[1-5][0-9]{2} http' file.txt
```

This matches numbers in the range 100-599, which is closer to the range of HTTP status codes.

Comment: Probably `^[1-5][0-9]{2}` is more accurate, since it is a [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no need for `cat` with `grep`. It can take a file argument itself.

You can do this:

```
grep '^[1-5][0-9]\{2\}[[:blank:]]\+http' file.txt
```

This will get you every line that matches with your criteria.

If you want only the return codes, you can run another grep or use other commands, for example with `cut`:

```
grep '^[1-5][0-9]\{2\}[[:blank:]]\+http' file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

and with grep,

```
grep '^[1-5][0-9]\{2\}[[:blank:]]\+http' file.txt | grep -o '^[0-9]\+'
```