# How to extract unix path in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Input

```
[security] [client 198.66.91.7] [domain testphp.example.com] [200] [/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD] (null)
```

Desired output

```
/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD
```

here is what I have so far

```
'.*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\]'
```

My Perl code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature 'say';

$txt='[modsecurity] [client 199.66.91.7] [domain testphp.vulnweb.com] [200] [/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD] (null)';


$re=''.*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\]'';

if ($txt =~ m/$re/is)
{
    $sbraces1=$1;
    say $1; 
}
```

output

```
/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD
```

I think my regex is messy? maybe another way?

Thanks

Comment: You should use a split approach.

Comment: Your comment should be an answer

Comment: @Deano I added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a split too... or a more general regex than the one you are using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = '[security] [client 198.66.91.7] [domain testphp.example.com] [200] [/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD] (null)';

my @fields = $data =~ /(?:\[(.*?)\])+/g;

print Dumper(\@fields);
```

The output you get is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'security',
          'client 198.66.91.7',
          'domain testphp.example.com',
          '200',                                                                                                                               
          '/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD'                                                            
        ];
```

So the fifth element of the returned array is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use character class negation. Because it is performance is better than the non greedy assertions.

```
my $txt = '[security] [client 198.66.91.7] [domain testphp.example.com] [200] [/apache/20160503/20160503-0636/20160503-063628-Vyh-LH8AAAEAAE6zC@AAAAAD] (null)';

my @array = $txt =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;

print "@array\n";
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/rZ7kA8/1)  demo for character class negation.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/gF5xT1/1)  demo for non greedy quantifier.

Comment: I like your solution. You should include the capture groups: `/\[([^\]]+)\]/g`

Answer (score 0):

I created this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM6eF6/1):

```
\[\d{3}\]\s+\[(\S+)\]
```

My answer is based on the assumption that the url that you want to match will always be followed by a HTTP status code.

Since it is HTTP status code we could also write (as in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001544/2549021)):

```
\[[1-5][0-9]{2}\]\s+\[(\S+)\]
```